# Run a library from the web in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom, node-modules

I'm trying to run a library which only has its client library as script to run through browsers. The Node.js module of it is only the server version. I can eval the script, but I constantly get errors of undefined `window`, `document`, `navigator`, `location` or `WebSocket`.

Is there any Node.js module to emulate these variables so I can load and use this web library just like any other Node.js module?

Comment: Code that uses `document`, `navigator` and  `location`, must be expecting some functionality that node.js does not have.  It seems you need to investigate what this module is trying to accomplish and see how it's using these and form a more educated opinion about whether it's even practical to use this code on the back-end.  Without seeing the code ourselves, we can't really help offer an analysis on that.

Comment: It would indeed help if you could mention the library you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [browser-run](https://github.com/juliangruber/browser-run) package:

```
var run = require('browser-run');

var browser = run();
browser.pipe(process.stdout);
browser.end('console.log(location); window.close()');
```